# python- add col names to np.array

Tags: python, numpy

Why the following works:

```
mat = np.array(
    [(0,0,0),
     (0,0,0),
     (0,0,0)],
    dtype=[('MSFT','float'),('CSCO','float'),('GOOG','float') ]
    )
```

while this doesn't:

```
mat = np.array(
    [[0]*3]*3,
    dtype=[('MSFT','float'),('CSCO','float'),('GOOG','float')]
    )
```

> TypeError: expected a readable buffer object

How can I create a matrix easily like

> [[None]*M]*N

But with tuples in it to be able to assign names to columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a number of 1D arrays (columns) you would like to merge while keeping column names, you can use [`np.rec.fromarrays`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.core.records.fromarrays.html):

```
>>> dt = np.dtype([('a', float),('b', float),('c', float),])
>>> np.rec.fromarrays([[0] * 3 ] * 3, dtype=dt)
rec.array([(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)], dtype=[('a', '<f8'), ('b', '<f8'), ('c', '<f8')])
```

This gives you a record/structured array in which columns can have names & different datatypes.

Comment: It's interesting that `rec.fromarrays` uses the copy-by-fields method of filling the structured array.

Answer (score 4):

When I make an zero array with your dtype

```
In [548]: dt=np.dtype([('MSFT','float'),('CSCO','float'),('GOOG','float') ])

In [549]: A = np.zeros(3, dtype=dt)

In [550]: A
Out[550]: 
array([(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)], 
      dtype=[('MSFT', '<f8'), ('CSCO', '<f8'), ('GOOG', '<f8')])
```

notice that the display shows a list of tuples.  That's intentional, to distinguish the `dtype` records from a row of a 2d (ordinary) array.

That also means that when creating the array, or assigning values, you also need to use a list of tuples.

For example let's make a list of lists:

```
In [554]: ll = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3).tolist()
In [555]: ll

In [556]: A[:]=ll
...
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'list'
```

but if I turn it into a list of tuples:

```
In [557]: llt = [tuple(i) for i in ll]

In [558]: llt
Out[558]: [(0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8)]

In [559]: A[:]=llt

In [560]: A
Out[560]: 
array([(0.0, 1.0, 2.0), (3.0, 4.0, 5.0), (6.0, 7.0, 8.0)], 
      dtype=[('MSFT', '<f8'), ('CSCO', '<f8'), ('GOOG', '<f8')])
```

assignment works fine.  That list also can be used directly in `array`.

```
In [561]: np.array(llt, dtype=dt)
Out[561]: 
array([(0.0, 1.0, 2.0), (3.0, 4.0, 5.0), (6.0, 7.0, 8.0)], 
      dtype=[('MSFT', '<f8'), ('CSCO', '<f8'), ('GOOG', '<f8')])
```

Similarly assigning values to one record requires a tuple, not a list:

```
In [563]: A[0]=(10,12,14)
```

The other common way of setting values is on a field by field basis.  That can be done with a list or array:

```
In [564]: A['MSFT']=[100,200,300]

In [565]: A
Out[565]: 
array([(100.0, 12.0, 14.0), (200.0, 4.0, 5.0), (300.0, 7.0, 8.0)], 
      dtype=[('MSFT', '<f8'), ('CSCO', '<f8'), ('GOOG', '<f8')])
```

The `np.rec.fromarrays` method recommended in the other answer ends up using the copy-by-fields approach.  It's code is, in essence:

```
arrayList = [sb.asarray(x) for x in arrayList]
<determine shape>
<determine dtype>
_array = recarray(shape, descr)
# populate the record array (makes a copy)
for i in range(len(arrayList)):
    _array[_names[i]] = arrayList[i]
```

Comment: this comes up quite a bit, is there a reason that the case of a list of lists hasn't been deemed an acceptable input instead of a list of tuples? I have yet to find a definitive rationale for this.

Comment: It seems logical to me that the input syntax will echo the display style.  But I haven't explored the issue on github issues or the developers forum.  As it is, beginners often miss the distinction between dtype fields and 2d columns, especially when they load a csv.  Someelse just asked why they couldn't add a structured array and a flat one.

Comment: I could imagine an argument coming from the fact that a `dtype` entry is defined as a 2-field sequence and thus set to be immutable.